# Conditional /etc/hosts file

Tags: windows-10, hosts, hosts-file, virtual-host

I am trying to add conditions based on ip accessing to localhost on windows 10:

/etc/hosts

```
if (ip == '192.168.0.102')
   127.0.0.1 www.site.co.uk site.co.uk
else
   #127.0.0.1 www.site.co.uk site.co.uk // disable it
```

I need this because I am developing on a site and from time to time I need to access the live version. And every time I need to change the /etc/hosts file. Is this possbile? What other solutions if not.

Comment: What you want cannot be done with the hosts file.

Comment: What do you mean by `ip accessing`?

Comment: There are plugins for chome that simulate a hosts file which can be turned on and off at will. They're made for this kind of dillemma because the hosts file does not support IF.

Comment: You can probably just write a script that sets the correct IP for you.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue.  Hostgator used to use a "temp url" to access a site under development before you pointed your nameservers to that ip.  Now the only method is to edit the hosts file and then you can't get to the live site without editing again.  Really annoying!

Answer (score 0):

Have two "reference" versions of the hosts file, and overwrite the existing file with the appropriate reference file.

IMHO, you might be better served (no pun intended) [by using a Windows Firewall (or third-party firewall) rule.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753558(v=ws.11).aspx) [Under some conditions, Windows 10 ignores hosts files.](https://www.petri.com/windows-10-ignoring-hosts-file-specific-name-resolution) You might create a PowerShell script that runs at startup to dis/enable a rule.